# Words to describe pleasure in keeping something or an activity secret

Tags: word-request

Is there a single English word that can be used to describe the deep pleasure that can be experienced when you keep something to yourself, especially, when it concerns an activity you engage in or take part in?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a specific word that combines both of these ideas, but I would probably say something like "the quiet enjoyment" or "the satisfaction of secrecy".
To me these sound more natural.

Answer (score 1):

> "Is there a single English word that can be used to describe the deep pleasure that can be experienced when you keep something to yourself, especially, when it concerns an activity you engage in or take part in?"

No.

But "secret pleasure" is a *common phrase*.

It suggests exactly what you mean.

***Be aware*** that "guilty pleasure" is the humorous version of what you're talking about. So, say someone is "addicted" to watching a cheesy, low-brow show on a streaming channel, that's a "guilty pleasure"